# (HELP)How to read Physical Dimensions in datasheets

Tags: electronics, components

Sir/ Ma'am,
.
How to read the dimension labels of this IC?[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have annotated your drawing a little to help you understand it better:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Values above the horizontal lines are in inches. Values below it are in mm.

Comment: why there is an plus and negative sign?

Comment: that is tolerance values, allowed variations in production (for instance). 0.060±0.005 is the range 0.055 to 0.065.